# How to make the google sheets app not auto changing the sheets text color?

Tags: android, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I actively use google sheets on my pc and phone
and very strange things happen with spreadsheets when I use it on my phone

it's just a test file not running any script and the phone automatically sets a different text color, does anyone have any idea how to get around this?

**i just want to get the same text color as on the pc**

A1: text color black, A2: text color white

android dark mode:

[image: android dark mode:]

android white mode:

[image: android white mode:]

pc:

[image: pc:]

Thanks in advance if you have any solutions!

Comment: Can you check if following this [steps](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9955476) keeps happening? It seems to have to do with the implementation of Dark Mode within the application.

Comment: yes i'm over it, that's why i put a picture of the white mode and the dark mode
(Dark, Light, or System default.)

Comment: Because of the image you have put in the Light Mode, the text disappears? Or just change the two colors to white?

Comment: @Emel
I have not changed anything
remained the same: A1: text color black, A2: text color white

Comment: I reproduce your steps and it's working for me. You could try replaying it to see if it happens again.

Comment: ohh shoot in android settings had to turn off dark mode and not in google sheets
now everything works, perfectly
sorry it was a basic user error, i should have turned it off first : (


| question, how do people who use dark mode on android solve this?
always turn dark mode on and off at android system?